# isGooglePlayServicesAvailable nullPointerException

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I use this method to check is Google Play available:

```
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
  do something
}
```

Everything is ok except with few devices. For now, I noticed a crash on Alcatel ONE TOUCH 4033X and Sony C2105. I constantly have crash reports on those devices and I have no idea why is that happening.

```
BRAND=TCT, PRODUCT=Yaris_M, TOTAL_MEM_SIZE=2246361088, AVAILABLE_MEM_SIZE=1537773568, CUSTOM_DATA=, STACK_TRACE=java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)

at package.ShopsFragment.servicesConnected(ShopsFragment.java:685)
at package.ShopsFragment.getLatAndLng(ShopsFragment.java:338)
at package.ShopsFragment.onConnected(ShopsFragment.java:673)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.hb$c.onConnected(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.hc.c(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.hc.cp(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.hb$h.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.hb$h.d(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.hb$b.fv(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.hb$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5400)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT: 
in onCreated I have:

```
if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) 
{
    if(network_enabled) 
    {
    getLocation();
    } 
}

public void getLocation() 
    {
        clearTextFromSearch = true;
        searchEditText.setText("");

        locationClient.connect();
    }
```

Then on onConnected I call getLatAndLng()

```
private void getLatAndLng() 
    {
        clearList = true;
        nPages = 0;

        clearTextFromSearch = true;
        searchEditText.setText("");

        currentLocation = locationClient.getLastLocation();

        locationClient.disconnect();

        if(currentLocation != null)
        {
            lat = currentLocation.getLatitude();
            lng = currentLocation.getLongitude();

            getShops(lat, lng, nPages);
        }
}
```

Comment: are you calling the method from onConnected callback? Can you post the code where you are calling it?

Comment: Difficult to say what is the problem. What is the line code 338 inside getLatAndLong()? From the stack it seems there is call to a method called serviceConnected() but I can't see it.

Comment: I think I found the problem. The problem was not related with GooglePlayServices. I'm working with fragments and when app is destroyed due to system constraints, if I'm in activity started from fragment when app is destroyed, when activity is recreated and I go back to fragment, context is lost because I don't save it in onSaveInstanceState.

Comment: @ĐorđeNilović I think you're right here. I was calling this in an `ASyncTask` and was referencing the parent `Activity`. I think I was getting this error because that parent `Activity` had disappeared, either through garbage collection or through closing the activity, etc. I am trying to use `WeakReference` instead so we'll see if that helps.